# Python singleton class member variable not allowing its value to be re-assigned?

Tags: python, singleton

I have a config.py singleton module containing:

```
class Singleton:
    """"""
    def __init__(self, name, bases, namespace):
        self._obj=type( name, bases, namespace )()

    def __call__(self):
        return self._obj


class ConfigObj(object):
    """"""
    __metaclass__ = Singleton


    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        self._dataOne = '0010'
        self._dataTwo = None

        print self._dataOne

    def setData(self,val)
        """"""
        self._dataTwo = val

    def getData(self)
        """"""
        return self._dataTwo

def Config():
    """Create instance of config singleton"""
    ConfigObj()

def ConfigSetData(val):
    """Set config data"""
    ConfigObj().setData(val)

def ConfigGetData():
    """Get config data"""
    return ConfigObj().getData()
```

I have a suite.py module containing:

```
Config()
ConfigSetData('22')
print ConfigGetData()
```

When run the singleton 'ConfigObj' is created as expected and the singleton object id persists. During debug it appears that self._dataTwo is reassigned.

However, when the ConfigGetData() func is called it shows that the value for self._dataTwo is still assigned as None and the print statement fails with a 'nontype' exception..

Any suggestions as to how to make the change to self._dataTwo persist is duely welcome?..

Comment: Please read http://sscce.org/. In particular note that should show sample input and output, and explain what is erroneous about it.

Comment: When I run your code after inserting the two missing colons in the code within config.py and adding a `from config import *` to the beginning of suite.py, I get the following output: `0010` and `22`, each on a separate line -- which seems correct.